# How to find index of object key in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I try to get the index of my selected value to show all deeper options.
My `JSON` looks like this:

```
{
  "flow": {
    "startmessage": "Hallo [name]",
    "questionmessage": "Waar heb je een vraag over?",
    "categories": [
      {
        "Openingstijden": [
          {"Hoe pas ik mijn openingstijden aan?": ["text 2"]},
          "Hoe upload ik een audio file?",
          "Hoe stel ik een doorschakeling in?",
          "Hoe stel ik een pauze in?"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Mijn bedrijfsgegevens": [
          "Hoe wijzig ik mijn bedrijfsgegevens?",
          "Hoe maak ik een nieuwe gebruiker aan?",
          "Mijn bedrijfsgegevens kloppen niet"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Mijn facturen": [
          "Hoe kan ik mijn facturen inzien?",
          "Ik heb geen factuur ontvangen",
          "Het bedrag op mijn factuur klopt niet!"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Mijn project": [
          "Hoe kan ik mijn projectstatus inzien?",
          "Waar kan ik mijn project terugvinden?",
          "Waarom moet ik een inventarisatiefomulier invullen?"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Mijn contract": [
          "Waar kan ik mijn contract terugvinden?",
          "De gegevens van mijn contract kloppen niet"
        ]
      },
      {
        "CDR's": [
          "Hoe exporteer ik mijn CDR's?",
          "Waarom werken mijn CDR's niet?",
          "Hoe filter ik mijn CDR's?"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried to do this to get the index of 'Openingstijden'.
`flow` is the name of the `JSON` object I gave.

```
var index = flow['flow']['categories'].findIndex(function(category) {
   return category == "Openingstijden";
});
```

I also tried this:

```
var index = Object.keys(flow['flow']['categories']).indexOf("Openingstijden");
```

This however always returns -1, so it says it cannot find it.
Does anyone know how to find the index and maybe how to make my `JSON` structure better?
Maybe I'm using a too complicated structure?!

Comment: try `flow['flow']['categories'].findindex((category) => 'Openingstijden' in obj)`

Comment: you can try using categories as a dictionary  instead of a list of dictionaries

Comment: You can easily findIndex using Lodash. (https://lodash.com/) `_.findIndex(_.get(data,'flow.categories'),'Openingstijden');`
I have assigned flow object as data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each array item is an object with the key you want to search for. With your current structure, map each array item to its key first:

```js
const flow={flow:{startmessage:"Hallo [name]",questionmessage:"Waar heb je een vraag over?",categories:[{Openingstijden:[{"Hoe pas ik mijn openingstijden aan?":["text 2"]},"Hoe upload ik een audio file?","Hoe stel ik een doorschakeling in?","Hoe stel ik een pauze in?"]},{"Mijn bedrijfsgegevens":["Hoe wijzig ik mijn bedrijfsgegevens?","Hoe maak ik een nieuwe gebruiker aan?","Mijn bedrijfsgegevens kloppen niet"]},{"Mijn facturen":["Hoe kan ik mijn facturen inzien?","Ik heb geen factuur ontvangen","Het bedrag op mijn factuur klopt niet!"]},{"Mijn project":["Hoe kan ik mijn projectstatus inzien?","Waar kan ik mijn project terugvinden?","Waarom moet ik een inventarisatiefomulier invullen?"]},{"Mijn contract":["Waar kan ik mijn contract terugvinden?","De gegevens van mijn contract kloppen niet"]},{"CDR's":["Hoe exporteer ik mijn CDR's?","Waarom werken mijn CDR's niet?","Hoe filter ik mijn CDR's?"]}]}};


const keys = flow['flow']['categories'].map(arr => Object.keys(arr)[0]);
const index = keys.indexOf("Openingstijden");

console.log(index);
```

It's quite strange to have objects with only one property, though, you might consider having `categories` being an array of objects, where one key is the unique string (eg, `Openingstijden`), and the other key is the array, eg:

```
  {
    label: "Openingstijden",
    arr: [
      {"Hoe pas ik mijn openingstijden aan?": ["text 2"]},
      "Hoe upload ik een audio file?",
      "Hoe stel ik een doorschakeling in?",
      "Hoe stel ik een pauze in?"
    ]
  }
```

Then you can look up the `label` property.

If you *often* want to look up an object by the label, then instead of an array of categories, use an object, where each key is the label, eg:

```
const flow = {
  "flow": {
    "startmessage": "Hallo [name]",
    "questionmessage": "Waar heb je een vraag over?",
    "categories": {
      "Openingstijden": [
        {"Hoe pas ik mijn openingstijden aan?": ["text 2"]},
        "Hoe upload ik een audio file?",
        "Hoe stel ik een doorschakeling in?",
        "Hoe stel ik een pauze in?"
      ]
    },
    "Mijn bedrijfsgegevens": [
      "Hoe wijzig ik mijn bedrijfsgegevens?",
      "Hoe maak ik een nieuwe gebruiker aan?",
      "Mijn bedrijfsgegevens kloppen niet"
    ],
    ...
```

Comment: Map is overkill here

Answer (score 1):

As commented, this should be enough

> flow['flow']['categories'].findindex((category) => 'Openingstijden' in obj)

Issue with your approach was that you were trying to get keys of an array and not object in it.

**Sample:**

```js
var flow = {
  "flow": {
    "startmessage": "Hallo [name]",
    "questionmessage": "Waar heb je een vraag over?",
    "categories": [{
        "Openingstijden": [{
            "Hoe pas ik mijn openingstijden aan?": ["text 2"]
          },
          "Hoe upload ik een audio file?",
          "Hoe stel ik een doorschakeling in?",
          "Hoe stel ik een pauze in?"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Mijn bedrijfsgegevens": [
          "Hoe wijzig ik mijn bedrijfsgegevens?",
          "Hoe maak ik een nieuwe gebruiker aan?",
          "Mijn bedrijfsgegevens kloppen niet"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Mijn facturen": [
          "Hoe kan ik mijn facturen inzien?",
          "Ik heb geen factuur ontvangen",
          "Het bedrag op mijn factuur klopt niet!"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Mijn project": [
          "Hoe kan ik mijn projectstatus inzien?",
          "Waar kan ik mijn project terugvinden?",
          "Waarom moet ik een inventarisatiefomulier invullen?"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Mijn contract": [
          "Waar kan ik mijn contract terugvinden?",
          "De gegevens van mijn contract kloppen niet"
        ]
      },
      {
        "CDR's": [
          "Hoe exporteer ik mijn CDR's?",
          "Waarom werken mijn CDR's niet?",
          "Hoe filter ik mijn CDR's?"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

var index = flow['flow']['categories'].findIndex((category) => 'Openingstijden' in category);

console.log(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the object that includes the flow object is assigned to a `data` variable:

```
let data = {
  "flow": {
    "startmessage": "Hallo [name]",
    "questionmessage": "Waar heb je een vraag over?",
    "categories": [
      {
        "Openingstijden": [
          {"Hoe pas ik mijn openingstijden aan?": ["text 2"]},
          "Hoe upload ik een audio file?",
          "Hoe stel ik een doorschakeling in?",
         "Hoe stel ik een pauze in?"
        ]
      },
  {
    "Mijn bedrijfsgegevens": [
      "Hoe wijzig ik mijn bedrijfsgegevens?",
      "Hoe maak ik een nieuwe gebruiker aan?",
      "Mijn bedrijfsgegevens kloppen niet"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Mijn facturen": [
      "Hoe kan ik mijn facturen inzien?",
      "Ik heb geen factuur ontvangen",
      "Het bedrag op mijn factuur klopt niet!"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Mijn project": [
      "Hoe kan ik mijn projectstatus inzien?",
      "Waar kan ik mijn project terugvinden?",
      "Waarom moet ik een inventarisatiefomulier invullen?"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Mijn contract": [
      "Waar kan ik mijn contract terugvinden?",
      "De gegevens van mijn contract kloppen niet"
    ]
  },
  {
    "CDR's": [
      "Hoe exporteer ik mijn CDR's?",
      "Waarom werken mijn CDR's niet?",
      "Hoe filter ik mijn CDR's?"
    ]
  }
]
  }
}

for (let i of data.flow.categories) {
  for (let j in i) {
    if (j === "Openingstijden") {
      console.log("index is: " + j);
    }
  }
}
```

I should note that using `in` to iterate objects is a bit tricky in case the object includes functions etc. In this case it does not so there is no reason not to use.